# Calling Method in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a method I have written. It compiles except for one line...

```
public class http extends Activity {

httpMethod();            //will not compile



public void httpMethod(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://site/api/");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String test = "hello";

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextView.setText(test);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}    
}
```

I'm not the best java guy, but I would think calling the method like so would get a response. "Hello" is not displayed however...

How do I properly call the method?

Comment: Show us your log errors and more code of your class (that makes the thing easy). If you are extending an **Activity** why don't you have at least the _onCreate_ method?

Comment: In addition to Jon's answer, you have to have Network operation in a separate thread. Consider AsyncTask, otherwise you'll get an exception if targeting android os is < 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Just to leave no-one in any doubt, this answer only addresses why you're getting a compile-time error. It does *not* address what you should be doing in which thread and at what time in Android.

Personally I would recommend that you put Android down for the moment, learn Java in a simpler environment (e.g. console apps) and then, when you're comfortable with the language, revisit Android and learn all the requirements of Android development - which are obviously much more than just the language.

---

You're trying to call a method as a statement directly within your class. You can't do that - it has to be part of a constructor, initializer block, other method, or static initializer. For example:

```
// TODO: Rename this class to comply with Java naming conventions
public class http extends Activity {
    // Constructor is able to call the method... or you could call
    // it from any other method, e.g. onCreate, onResume
    public http() {
        httpMethod();
    }

    public void httpMethod() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Note that I've *only* given this example to show you a valid Java class. It *doesn't* mean you should actually be calling the method from your constructor.

Comment: That's all good and well now. My problem is it still isn't displaying "test". Is there an error there?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Urrrm, using a constructor in an Android `Activity` is generally not a good thing to do (unless the dev fully understands the implications). The usual place to do what the OP wants would be in `onCreate(...)`, `onResume()` or, more likely in something like a `Button` event handler. Thinking about it further, using a constructor will fail for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Squonk: That really was just an example. Will add more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet : My point is that not only will calling the `httpMethod()` from a constructor fail, but defining constructors for a class which extends `Activity` is an advanced topic. It can be done but there are few cases where it needs to be done and the dev should fully understand what the implications are and what can/can't be done from a constructor.

Comment: @Squonk: Fair enough - it looks like the OP should really take a step back and learn the basics of Java before continuing...

Comment: @JonSkeet: It comes down to more than the OP learning *the basics of Java*. The OP mostly needs to learn about the Android `Activity` class and also not to put the 'java' tag on questions related to Android (unless relevant). I edit to remove the 'java' tag from SO questions when I see they're specific to Android (particularly related to `Activity`) simply because *"valid Java"* (to quote your caveat) does not always apply. The code in the OP's question is broken but the example in your answer won't fix it. I wonder how many of the up-voters on your answer know anything about Android.

Comment: @squonk: I never said the OP *only* needed to learn the basics of Java. I'm just saying that I think it would be better to learn the basics of Java *first* (away from Android entirely) before trying to learn Android-specific requirements. Valid Java code isn't sufficient - but it is necessary.

Comment: @Squonk: Have now added a disclaimer to the top of my answer, which will hopefully satisfy you

Answer (score 2):

```
httpMethod();
```

should be inside some other method/constructor (or) assigned to variable. I suspect your requirement might be calling calling `httpMethod()` in either `onCreate()` (or) `onResume()` because you are extending Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you need to learn more about Android [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) and in particular the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class and the `Activity` lifecycle.

Your first problem is related to attempting to set a test string on your `TextView`.

DO NOT attempt to do this in any method which is called by the constructor. Perhaps more importantly, forget about ever defining a constructor (or constructors) for any class you create which extends `Activity`.

In order to be able to manipulate the UI elements of an `Activity`, the content view must be inflated. This is done either implicitly using `setContentView(...)` or explicitly using `LayoutInflater`. It is most usual to do this in `onCreate(...)` and until this is done, attempting to use `findViewById(...)` will return `null`. This is why attempting to do anything with the UI from an `Activity` constructor will fail unless you explicitly inflate your layout within the constructor (or another method called by it). I'm not sure it's even possible to inflate the layout at this point and it's certainly not something I'd recommend even if it is possible. As I said, forget about constructors for `Activities`.

To do what you want to do (for test purposes) you would need to do something like...

```
public class HttpActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        httpMethod();
    }

    public void httpMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your second problem, as Maxim's comment on your question, even though my example will work for older versions of Android, more recent versions will throw an exception if you attempt to perform network operations on the main thread (aka UI thread) as they are potentially time-consuming and can cause the thread to be blocked. As Maxim suggests you should do this with an `AsyncTask` or on some other `Thread` than the main (UI) thread.